# How does iTunes run on my computer?

Tags: windows-10, path

If I go to the search bar (Windows 10) and type iTunes, I get iTunes. I click on it and it runs.

However, if I try to find it on my computer, it doesn't exist. Just a 0 byte placeholder.

```
C:\>dir \itunes.* /s /a-d
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D42A-B3A4

 Directory of C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0\UsageLogs

05/19/2021  09:34 AM             1,307 iTunes.exe.log
               1 File(s)          1,307 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa

04/24/2021  04:21 AM                 0 iTunes.exe
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

C:\>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: It runs from here:  "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"   I have it running here and have  a shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: Somewhat related answer https://superuser.com/questions/1656218/command-prompt-cant-find-windows-terminal-even-though-it-detects-the-files-pat/1656220#1656220

Comment: @John - A UWP version of iTunes exists.  The author's copy exists in the WindowsApps directory.

Comment: One can use the UWP version or the regular version. The regular version works much better for me.

Comment: @John But there is no itunes.exe at those locations???

Comment: As @Ramhound noted you likely have the UWP version of IiTunes which puts iTunes in the UWP location.

Comment: @DavidThielen - UWP applications do not have an .exe file likewise you also don’t have the necessary permissions to view the contents of the folder with File Explorer or a command prompt.  If you believe the installation is corrupt you should reinstall the application with the Microsoft Store application.  The folder you have listed in your question is the local application data directory and not the installation directory of the UWP application in question

Comment: @Ramhound Let me go to the reason I asked this in the first place. How can I put a shortcut on my desktop to iTunes?

Comment: The simplest method? Install the desktop version of iTunes.  While it’s possible to create a desktop shortcut to a UWP application it also is extremely tricky

Comment: Navigate to *shell:AppsFolder* and right click on iTunes and select the option to create a shortcut

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you - the  shell:AppsFolder worked great. That's an amazing knowledge you have of Windows.